# Configuring Mbrola with meSpeak

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, espeak

What is the correct way to configure Mbrola Voices to meSpeak?

I have attempted to the usual method of configuration.
ex:

```
 {
"voice_id":"us-mbrola-1",
"dict_id":"en_dict",
"dict":"~Base64 String~",
"voice":"name us-mbrola-1\nlanguage en-us\nlanguage en 8\ngender female\nphonemes en-us\ndictrules 3 6\nstressLength 170 135 205 205 0 0  245 275\npitch 140 220\nmbrola us1 us_phtrans",
"voice_encoding":"text"
}
```

I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation". Please help me out to configure this properly.

Comment: You are not includinf the parameter `files` maybe because of that?