# How to play with different voices in mespeak.js

Tags: javascript, browser, text-to-speech, client-side

I am currently working on mespeak.js

I want to use a client side library that helps me convert text to speech without using any installed voices. mespeak.js helps to work on this problem but has very robotic voice. I want to use other voice but have a hard time configuring it in mespeak.js.

I tried following the documentation and it doesn't yields the required result and stuck with error.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205492/configuring-mbrola-with-mespeak) I tried implementing something similar to this.

```json
{
  "voice_id": "mb-en1",
  "voice":    "name english-mb-en1 \nlanguage en-uk  3 \nlanguage en 2 \ngender male \nvoicing 150 \npitch 82 117 \nmbrola en1 en1_phtrans",
  "voice_encoding": "text",
  "files" : [{
      "path": "path/to/en1_phtrans",
      "data": "en1_phtrans",
    }]
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.